# .NET Core CosmosDB get multiple documents with Session

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the latest .NET Core client library (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos) for CosmosDB and am trying to use it with the default consistency level of Session. I can successfully return the session token from updates, and can use that to retrieve a single item using ReadItemAsync, passing in the options with the SessionToken.

The way that seems to be preferred by examples to retrieve multiple documents is to use GetItemQueryIterator, however I cannot see a way to pass the session token into this. There does not appear to be a similar SessionToken property on the QueryRequestOptions class.

Is there a different method I have overlooked for retrieving multiple documents that will take the session token, or should I be doing this a completely different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a missing property on QueryRequestOptions, but after raising [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/973) and a pull request to fix it, it has now been added to V3.5.0.